# Chow groups with coefficients in a local system

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, local-systems

$\newcommand{\CH}{\mathrm{CH}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathscr{F}}
$
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a field $k$. Let $\F$ be a local system on $X$, i.e. a locally constant sheaf (for Zariski topology).

> How can we define the Chow groups of $X$ with coefficients in $\F$ ?

Such a definition should satisfy the following conditions:

1) If $\F$ is the constant sheaf $\Bbb Z_X$ on $X$ (resp. $\Bbb Q_X$), then we should find that $\CH^j(X, \F) = \CH^j(X)$ is the usual Chow group (resp. $\CH^j(X) \otimes_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb Q$ is the Chow group taking equivalence classes of divisors with rational coefficients).

2) If $H^{\bullet}$ is a [Weil cohomology theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_cohomology_theory), we should get (functorial?) *cycle class maps* 
$$\CH^j(X, \F) \to H^{2j}(X, \F).$$

I did not find any reference about such constructions.
Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You can take the motivic cohomology $H^{2j}(X,\mathcal{F}(j))$. But are you sure that there are locally constant sheaves for the Zariski topology ?

Comment: @Roland : thank you for your comment. I don't know motivic cohomology… But you may be right, I think that actually $\F$ is a locally constant sheaf on $X(\Bbb C)$ ($X$ being an algebraic variety over $k = \Bbb Q$, say), for the _analytic_ topology. What would happen in that case?

Comment: Well, you need to give it a "motivic" structure. I mean, if you want to get a cycle class map to étale cohomology, your local system needs to have some algebraic structure on it. Do you have a more precise question in mind ?

Comment: Dear @Roland, thank you for your comment. I see what you mean. Actually, my question arises from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.2999.pdf#page=107), where « there is a local system $F$ on $Σ(G)$ over $E$ » and there is the « Chow group of $Σ(G)$ with coefficients in $F$ ». If I have time, I will add the notations to make the context clear.

Comment: By the way, Rost introduces the Chow group with coefficients here : https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-01/16.pdf.  I don't know if this is the same kind of coefficients as in your article.

Comment: Motivation behind this question: p. 116 of  SYMPLECTIC LOCAL ROOT NUMBERS, CENTRAL CRITICAL L-VALUES, AND RESTRICTION PROBLEMS IN THE REPRESENTATION THEORY OF CLASSICAL GROUPS WEE TECK GAN, BENEDICT H. GROSS AND DIPENDRA PRASAD (GGP).